# Python Open() gives "invalid argument" error if file already exists

Tags: python

My python code is behaving weird and I don't know why:

```
with open("test.txt", "w") as f: 
    f.write("this is a test")

with open("test.txt", 'w') as f2:
    f2.write("this is also a test")
```

`test.txt` is created and `"this is a test"` is written to it. But the second statement gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 6, in <module>
    with open("test.txt", 'w') as f2:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'test.txt'
```

To my knowledge, `'w'` would overwrite this file.
Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

EDIT: 
I tried the code above on a different machine. Here it has the desired effect of overwriting the code. The question thus changes: What causes python to change its behaviour like this?

Comment: cannot reproduce

Comment: Is this the exact code you're running? No other lines (like `from os import *`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-installed python. 
This fixed the problem. The code in the example worked perfectly.

The "w" replaces contents of the file. 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
f = open("test.txt", "w")
f.write("this is a test")
f.close()

f2 = open("test.txt", "w")
f2.write("this is also a test")
f2.close()
```

I think the issue is you're trying to work with another instance of the same file without closing it, that being said writing this should also work:

```
f2.close()
```

Comment: Python isn't like a person so when you write an algorithm it follows step by step (won't skip a step if it's already done) in this case you told it to open the file write to it then open it again but you can't open a file that is already open. you know? :)

Comment: wouldnt the With statement close the file after indentation?

Comment: I don't believe so, haven't really looked into file handling but when I learnt about it I had always done it the way I showed you and was told to always close it so I took it to always need explicit closing cause I learnt psuedocode at the time as well and you'd always have to close the file there so I'm not too sure tbh, sorry :/

Comment: This is absolutely the wrong thing to do. The `with` statement guarantees that the file will be closed, even if an exception is raised in the body of the statement. The context manager essentially catches and re-raises the exception, closing the file in between.